# jQuery UI 1.8.13 sudden error

Tags: jquery-ui

We have been using Jquery from this link http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js for drag and drop. Suddenly we notice it is not working now and there is no code change done our side. We notice the error is pointing to these line and error is TypeError: a.curCSS is not a function? What will be solution to this problem?

```
e&&e.call(i)},g)}):this._focus.apply(this,arguments)},scrollParent:function(){var g;g=a.browser.msie&&/(static|relative)/.test(this.css("position"))||/absolute/.test(this.css("position"))?this.parents().filter
```

Comment: Solved just replaced it with the old jquery script is fine now. Thank you.

Comment: If your problem is solved, would you please select the answer that helped you most?

Answer (score 71):

This javascript error is caused by jQuery and jQueryUI being out of sync with each other.  Rather than go back to an older version of jQuery, I would update jQuery UI.  This [link](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/08/jquery-ui-1-8-23/) from the jQueryUI blog talks about support for the latest version jQuery.  I experienced the same error before updating jQuery UI.

Comment: Appreciating for posting this answer. The simplest and accurate to solve my problem without changing my code.

Answer (score 39):

Base on another answer... I did something slightly different...

Instead of replacing:

```
$.curCSS(element, attrib, val);
```

with:

```
$(element).css(attrib, val);
```

I created a new function:

```
$.curCSS = function (element, attrib, val) {
    $(element).css(attrib, val);
};
```

Answer (score 13):

`$.curCSS`: This method is simply an alias for `jQuery.css()` from jQuery 1.3 onward. Although it has never been part of the documented API, some external code has been known to use it, perhaps thinking it was “more efficient.” Now it’s “more gone.” - from [the page here](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/).

This error can occur by using `curCSS` also.

replace:

```
$.curCSS(element, attrib, val);
```

with

```
$(element).css(attrib, val);
```

Answer (score 8):

I had same problemm. Search for a link like this in your project:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js

and change it with this:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

It worked for me.

Comment: That in explanation by loading the exact version rater than using latest version.