# c.curCSS is not a function bug from jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am getting this errors message in console.

```
c.curCSS is not a function
...,m,n){c.each(e,function(){g-=parseFloat(c.curCSS(f,"padding"+this,true))||0;if(m...
```

This my function who does the autocomplete:

```
function autocomplete_name (name_val, id_val,action, button) {

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(name_val).autocomplete({
                source: function( request, response ) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: action,
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            term: request.term

                        },
                        success: function( data ) {
                            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.name,
                                    value: item.name,
                                    id: item.id
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 2,
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    $(id_val).val(ui.item.id);
                    $(name_val).val(ui.item.value);
                    $(button).trigger("click")
                }
            });

        });

}
```

I have jQuery 1.8.3 version and I do not have access to the file. It is from another server, I just use a link to the library. The function works, but there is no css apply to the results and i am getting that error message in console. **YES I saw solutions that I have to modified the library, but I do not have acccess to do that.**
What should I do in order to make this work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI 1.8.13 sudden error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048271/jquery-ui-1-8-13-sudden-error)

Comment: @Terry As I said in the post. I do not have access to the library. Your solution is about to modify the library. I am looking for another solution, which do not modify the library. Pay more attention please before mark it as duplicated

Comment: @Jozsef, if you cannot modify the library, why don't you simply alias `$.curCSS()` to `$.css()` in your own module?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi please tell me how, or how can I do that. This is the first time that I face curCss. I didn't hear about this before :), thx

Comment: You said you "do not have access to the file" but **you did not say you cannot reference a newer version of jQuery UI**. The duplicate question I linked simply instructed users to use a newer version—nobody is asking you to modify the core UI files yourself. Perhaps you should revise your question's context and circumstance before anything else.

Answer (score 63):

As a workaround, you could simply redefine `$.curCSS()` in your module.

After including jQuery, write something like:

```
jQuery.curCSS = function(element, prop, val) {
    return jQuery(element).css(prop, val);
};
```

jQuery UI will end up calling that function afterwards, and the autocomplete widget will work as intended.

*Update:* I just realized my answer is a quasi-duplicate of Johann Chaves Saborío's answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16594729/464709). I will leave it here, though, because my function propagates the return value of `$.css()` to the caller, but his doesn't.

Comment: Thanks! This also works with the same error I got with fullcalendar.io (using an old version that used jQueryUI 1.8 I believe).

Comment: This should also work: `jQuery.curCSS = jQuery.css;`