# Jquery, cannot access css properties of dynamically generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery to append elements to a div, and all works fine.

```
var new_div = $('<div>My stuff</div>');
new_div.appendTo("#container");
```

However, I'd like the div to appear by fading in, instead of abruptly.

I notice though that I get an error when I try to access graphic properties on my dynamically generated element. So this, for example fails:

```
 new_div.hide().fadeIn();
```

The console reports the following error:

```
 TypeError: jQuery.curCSS is not a function
```

Do I understand this correctly, that this fails because current css properties are not defined for the dynamically generated element? Or what else can be goingg wrong?

**Important edit**
Additional checking and working on this pointed out to a complete misunderstanding from my part. This has nothing to do with the fact that the element was dynamically generated. I got the same thing by calling fadeIn() on whatever element.
I sincerely apologize!
I still didn't get, though, why this happens

Comment: You forgot parenthesis after .hide. `new_div.hide().fadeIn();` should work. The TypeError seems to belong to something else?

Comment: since jquery 1.8.0 curCSS method has being removed from jquery core. Use css() instead.

Comment: @Mois44, ops, sorry, misspelled while writing the answer. That isn't it though, as it was correct in my original code

Comment: @Karlos, I read as much, but how exactly am I "using" them? I am just using hide() and fadeIn()

Comment: it could be the jquery core if you don't implicitly wrote curCSS in your code...

Comment: I tried your code and it worked fine for me. Maybe take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12216396/6258292

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyNXRd  working fine - there has to bee another problem

Comment: @DavidTonarini Do you use jquery UI at the same time ?

Comment: @Mois44 Yeah, I saw that question too, I think also this has to do with some incompatibility with jQuery and UI, but I don't seem to be figuring out how. Both are at the current version

Comment: @jsurf yes, I have both jQuery and UI

Comment: @DavidTonarini probably jQuery and jQuery UI might be out of sync. take a look for the answer of Eric Brenden here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048271/jquery-ui-1-8-13-sudden-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seem to be a compatibility question, although I wasn't able to figure out exactly why and how to fix it.
Adding this code fixes the problem though:

```
jQuery.curCSS = function(element, prop, val) {
  return jQuery(element).css(prop, val);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding elements to the DOM takes some time, miliseconds maybe, but it's still a reason for jquery not be able to find the element.
This process might be even slower if the DOM is a large html page.

Write your code like this:

```
var new_div = $('<div>My stuff</div>');
new_div.appendTo("#container");
setTimeout( function(){ 

    new_div.hide().fadeIn(); 

} , 150); // 100 could be also good
```

It might be enough time for jquery to catch the element.

Comment: FYI: You can manipulate the new element even before appending it to another element. It's created in the first line and referenced by the variable "new_div". This has nothing to do with asynchronicity (also, DOM manipulations like appendTo aren't asynchron).

Answer (score 0):

I would add an id to keep track of all elements I'm creating (just my preference, but it makes it easier to code it).

```
var new_div = '<div id="myNewDiv1" style="display:none;">My Styff</div>'
$('body').append(new_div);
$('#myNewDiv1').fadeIn();
```